# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: java, json, reactjs, websocket, jetty

While connecting to REACT based WebSocket client to Java Jetty based Web Socket server, I am getting the error below -

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2319/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
```

This error doesn't exist while connecting through Chrome's Smart Web Socket client.

I am trying to develop Web Socket Client based on REACT. Client code is -

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2319/ws');
     connection.onopen = function () {
     // connection is opened and ready to use
    };
```

WebSocket Server has been based on Jetty. Server code is -

```
server = new Server();
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(SSConstants.WWBSOCKET_PORT);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
    // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/ws"); // Set to "/ws" for future integration with the main jetty server.
    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        // Initialize javax.websocket layer
        ServerContainer wsContainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);

        // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
        wsContainer.addEndpoint(WebsocketListener.class);
        server.start();           
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        ssLogger.logInfo("Websocket Server start exp : ");
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

Output -

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2319/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

Request URL:ws://localhost:2319/ws
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found

Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 11 Aug 2017 18:51:42 GMT
Location:http://localhost:2319/ws/
Server:Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)

Request Headers
view source
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:localhost:2319
Origin:https://localhost:1338
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:2OZooIjOX7G6kgNpPOz9Fw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Name
```

Answer (score 7):

`ws://localhost:2319/ws` is not the valid endpoint URL/URI, it wants to redirect to the correct one for your declared `contextPath` of `/ws`

That's what the 302 redirect is telling you ...

`Location: http://localhost:2319/ws/`

Lets say your `WebsocketListener` is declared as `@ServerEndpoint("/ws")`, and we use your `ServletContext` at `contextPath` of `"/ws"` that would mean your URL/URI to access that websocket endpoint is  ...

`ws://localhost:2319/ws/ws`

Or said in a different way ...

`ws://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/<endpointPath>`

Answer (score -1):

I recently faced the same issue and this is how I was able to resolve mine.

I changed the port number for my websocket server from 8080 to 8335 which was the same is the same port for my Apache server.

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8335
);

$server->run();
```

And also made the same changes in my javascript code for the actual connection

```
let conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8335');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");

    conn.send('Hello Everyone');
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    $("#msg").append('<br>'+e.data);
};
```

You can also lookup for free ports in the Apache controller by following the images below. Thanks

[click on Netstart on the Xampp Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miLKy.png)

enter image description here

[Click to refresh to view Active Socket, New Sockets and Old Sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWkzI.png)

[Select any of the ports that falls in the burgundy section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUSyt.png)

Thank you