# websocket closes connection on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a websocket java application installed on VM of compute engine of google cloud platform. If the request goes through google load balancer the websocket closed automatically, however if I access using IP it works fine. I have increased the backend service timeout to 86400 seconds but it does not solve the issue any clues pls ?

```
location /openWebSocket {

proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_http_version  1.1;

proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_read_timeout 7d;
proxy_send_timeout 7d;
keepalive_timeout 7d;
```

}

Below is the nginx access.log info

```
[21/Jan/2019:21:16:57 +0000] "GET /openWebSocket HTTP/1.1" 
101 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 [21/Jan/2019:21:17:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" 
"GoogleHC/1.0"
[21/Jan/2019:21:17:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" 
"GoogleHC/1.0"
[21/Jan/2019:21:17:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" 
"GoogleHC/1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support), GCP Load balancer supports websockets natively and can act as a proxy as long as the following conditions are met :

- After a successful connection, the client issues a websocket Upgrade request.
- The backend (In your case the Java app) issues a successful websocket Upgrade response.

I would check in the GCP load balancer logs or in the Java app logs if there is an error during the websocket handshake. I would look for an error similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655753/error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-302)

If so, I would suggest checking your code handling of the Websocket Upgrade response.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added the request/response I see in nginx. In chrome I do not see any handshake error, connection is established successfuly and then after 100 seconds or so it gets closed automatically

Comment: I have deployed a stomp based websocket and it seems to work fine. I see the heart beat data frames being sent to client and server. May be I need to adapt the same to keep the connection alive and not close

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the timeout values on the backend usually resolves these types of issues.

You can also look into [Session Affinity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) which is still in beta at the moment.

Comment: I have increased the timeout value of the backend and there is only one instance behind the loadbalancer so I dont think session affinity will apply here

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I couldn’t find any error messages in the log samples you posted. 

Can you also give us more details on what your application is doing? 

There is also a [parameter in nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_timeout) that tracks the length of time between successive writes of the request body, and defaults to 60 seconds. Did you check this as well? 

How frequently are you sending data? We need more details to understand what is happening.

Comment: sending heart beat msgs resolved this issue. I was not getting error, but the socket would be closed automatically